# Hibernate custom validator with object object type parameter in annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I want use hibernate validator. I want to create a custom constrain validation the can be validate using an annotation like this

```
@DeliveryTime(hotelenv)
private Date deliveryTime;
```

hotelenv is an object of a class called `HotelEnv`.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Annotations are *static* metadata to your code that you provide at compile time. You cannot pass variables to annotations. However, you can implement it like this `@DeliveryTime(HotelEnv.class)`, if that suits your needs. But if you need to populate the valid delivery time from an object you are stuck here.

Comment: so can I pass like two java.sql.Time in the the annotation like @DeliveryTime(time1,time2)

Comment: Is that a question? If so, the answer is "Not in Java". `@DeliveryTime ("4:00am", "6:12pm")` is as close as it gets.